# ClickOnce deployment for restricted users

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, deployment, clickonce, publishing

From firsthand experience, it appears that ClickOnce only installs for the current user, and there is no option to install for all users.  This is a problem because some users within the company need to use ClickOnce applications but do not have permissions to install applications (for security reasons).

So far, the only solution we have to this problem is to grant the user in question permission to install programs, let them install the ClickOnce program, and then revoke their privileges. It seems as if there should be a better solution for this problem.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, as my post says, we are able to elevate the user's privileges to standard privileges and then tell them to install. This is is not ideal because it requires that we guide the user through the process over the phone and it is a very time consuming/inefficient process.

Comment: I was been waiting for a more ideal solution but I guess there isn't one. Distributing via group policy has worked and will work, but ClickOnce is preferred because it is a much more streamlined process. It just popped into my head that maybe they could install if application wasn't full trust.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ClickOnce should allow these users to install anyway.  That's the point of ClickOnce: it allows restricted users to install your app. Otherwise you could just distribute an msi using group policy.

Comment: I guess distributing via group policy is the only solution at this point in time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should seek an .MSI based installation to do this (Wise for windows installer, Install Shield, or use Visual Studio built in packager). ClickOnce is designed to install for and only for the current user, as the files are stored in the installed user's app directory.

Comment: what if one's app targets the .NET Framework 4.0 and it must be installed for the app to run? Does the framework get placed into the user's app directory by the ClickOnce installer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but I think ClickOnce is not a good solution for your use case.  Clickonce deployement is a website exposing your application and ClickOnce will install a new version of the application if needed.
If your user has access to the site the only thing who can stop him are the permissions requested by your application, or the asInvoker/ requireAdministrator/ highestAvailable elements of your manifeste.